# I'm new with ubuntu 16.04 and I am unable to connect to the iternet on an old mac 2008

Tags: wireless, mac

I'm new with ubuntu and I am unable to connect to the internet via wifi [wired connection not an issue]. On an old mac 2008.
Right now I'm connected via the ethernet cable but as soon as I disconnect I'm kaput. I just seem unable to fix it :(

Comment: Please [edit] the full output of `sudo lshw -C network` into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0280]'; rfkill list`? Thanks.